# PDF of an order statistics divided by a parameter

Tags: self-study, density-function, order-statistics

Let $$ x_{1}, x_{2}, ... x_{n}  $$

be IID uniform on $$ [0,\theta] $$

Find the PDF of $$ \frac {x_{(n)}} {\theta} $$

The way I initially though about this question is to find the pdf of nth order statistics, but I do not how to proceed from there.

Now I saw the solution, I know I was supposed to find the CDF and then differentiate to get the PDF.

However, I just want to know is there any way to get to the answer from my initial approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remember that

$ x_{(n)}=Max \{x_1,...,x_n\} $

and

$ F_{x_{(n)}}(x)={F(x)}^n = (\frac{x}{\theta})^n  $ on $ 0 < x<\theta $

then

$F_{\frac{x_{(n)}}{\theta}}(x)=P(\frac{x_{(n)}}{\theta}<x) = P(x_{(n)}<x\theta ) $

$= (\frac{(x\theta)}{\theta})^n $ on $0 < x\theta < \theta $

dividing theta

$= x^n $ on $0 < x < 1 $

These problems are typically tedious because you have to consider the limits of their distribution